# How can I get youtube-dl to match all videos in a channel that have a particular word in the title?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I want to archive all the videos in a YouTube channel, but I want to save some at a lower quality and others at a higher quality based on their title.

According to the docs, it seems like `--match-title` should do the trick, but I'm running into a snag: it seems to also be used to match **playlist** titles, which can stop the traversal of the channel before any video titles are checked.  For instance:

```
$ youtube-dl --version
2021.01.24.1
$ youtube-dl --match-title Oscilloscope --simulate https://www.youtube.com/c/EevblogDave
[youtube:tab] EevblogDave: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: EEVblog - Home
[youtube:tab] playlist EEVblog - Home: Downloading 5 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 5
[download] "Uploads" title did not match pattern "Oscilloscope"
[download] Downloading video 2 of 5
[download] "Popular uploads" title did not match pattern "Oscilloscope"
[download] Downloading video 3 of 5
[download] "Multimeter Reviews" title did not match pattern "Oscilloscope"
[download] Downloading video 4 of 5
[download] "Electronics Tutorials" title did not match pattern "Oscilloscope"
[download] Downloading video 5 of 5
[download] "Created playlists" title did not match pattern "Oscilloscope"
[download] Finished downloading playlist: EEVblog - Home
$
```

I think the `--match-title Oscilloscope` **should** have matched [EEVblog #1368​ - Active Oscilloscope Probes COMPARED (Part 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlSb8hdFtTY), but it didn't, because none of the channel playlists have "Oscilloscope" in their titles.

[image: EEVBlog channel page with video that should have matched highlighted]

How can I do accept matching over all the videos on a channel without running into this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `/videos` to the end of your url.

Comment: Can you include an example?

Comment: well fek if this isn't the easiest answer that I didn't think to try...